# TabBar Item, every viewDidLoad called when app launch

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

The iPad app, I have a `TabBarViewController` which contain five VC:A,B,C,D,E.
When app launch, every `ViewDidLoad` called, after that I click the tabBar item, the `viewDidLoad` won't called again.

I don't know why?

Thanks for help!

Comment: are you saying that you are not able to view the content on 2nd instance of tap on each tabs view controller?

Comment: Are you sure you mean viewDidLoad? It should only be called for the controller in the first tab when the app launches. After that, it will be called for the other controllers the first time they're viewed.

Comment: i am sure, two days ago,the app run normally,but yestoday i have this problem

Comment: Well, you'll have to post your code if you want some help.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that every `viewDidLoad` is being called on its own upon application launch, then there must be something you're doing to trigger these events. If however, you mean that each `viewDidLoad` is only being called the first time you select each tab, then yes this is the intended behavior. Loading each view controller into memory as it's needed.

If you're interested in being notified every time a view controller was selected and therefore about to appear on screen, add the logic to `viewWillAppear`: instead of `viewDidLoad`.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: for TabBarViewController,normally, only when i Click the item, the viewDidLoad called. i check my code,i have do nothing to trigger these events. two days ago,the app is Ok,but yestoday i encounter this problem

Comment: i have find the reason, i put the line code self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:240.0/255.0 green:237.0/255.0 blue:236.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]; in - (id)initWithNibName.... . but i  don't know why self.view.backgroundColor=... can trigger viewDidload.

Comment: @wit, accessing the `view` property of a view controller causes it to load the view (and then call `viewDidLoad` when it's done)